# ionic cordova android disable soft keyboard when touch input filed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, disable

I need to disable the soft keyboard when the user focuses on an input field.
I am using ionic 4 and cordova 8 for android.

I have to do this because the app will be used on a device with a physical keyboard and I would therefore like to use this physical keyboard

how can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try to add

```
ng-readonly="true"
```

to your input in the HTML file